# C# can't get datas from stored procedure with opendatasource and Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0

Tags: c#, sql-server, stored-procedures, http-get, oledbconnection

I have a strange issues reading data from an Eexcel file.
I made a query in SQL Server with `OPENDATASOURCE`:

```
    SELECT COMPETENZA, [CODICE CLEINTE], [RAGIONE SOCIALE], MODELLO, VARIANTE, 
  TIPOLOGIA, ESSENZA, FINITURA, TAPPEZZERIA, COMMESSA, ROUND([% MOL SU RICAVI NETTI] * 100,2) as MARGINE
  FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', 
   'Data Source=K:\UTENTI\SAMUELE\temp id commesse\ID Commesse produzione.xls;Extended Properties=EXCEL 12.0')...['Consuntivi produzione$']
  WHERE MODELLO IS NOT NULL AND [% MOL SU RICAVI NETTI] IS NOT NULL
```

If I execute this query in a stored procedure, it works fine.

But when I execute from C# by an `HttpGet` I get this issues:

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException (0x80131904): Cannot initialize the data source object of OLE DB provider "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" for linked server "(null)".

This is my C# code:

```
[HttpGet]
    public async Task<JsonResult> GetMarginiCommessaListJSON()
    {
        var yourdata = GetMarginiCommessaList();

        return Json(new { data = yourdata });
    }

    public List<MarginiCommessa> GetMarginiCommessaList()
    {
        SqlDataReader reader;
        SqlConnection sqlConn = new SqlConnection(_configuration["dbConnectionString"]);
        string sqlCmdStr = "MARGINI_COMMESSE";
        SqlCommand sqlCmd = new SqlCommand(sqlCmdStr, sqlConn);
        sqlCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        List<MarginiCommessa> allestList = new List<MarginiCommessa>();

        try
        {
            using (sqlConn)
            {
                sqlConn.Open();
                reader = sqlCmd.ExecuteReader();
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    allestList.Add(new MarginiCommessa
                    {
                        anno = reader.GetValue(0).ToString(),
                        codCli = reader.GetValue(1).ToString(),
                        nomCli = reader.GetValue(2).ToString(),
                        modello = reader.GetValue(3).ToString(),
                        variante = reader.GetValue(4).ToString(),
                        tipologia = reader.GetValue(5).ToString(),
                        essenza = reader.GetValue(6).ToString(),
                        finitura = reader.GetValue(7).ToString(),
                        tapezzeria = reader.GetValue(8).ToString(),
                        commessa_qta = reader.GetValue(9).ToString(),
                        margine = reader.GetValue(10).ToString()
                    });
                }
                reader.Close();
                sqlConn.Close();
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            System.IO.File.WriteAllText(GlobalVariables.errorFolderLocation + "GetMarginiCommessaListJSON.txt", e.ToString());
        }

        return allestList;
    }
```

And this is my Stored procedure:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[MARGINI_COMMESSE]
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;

  SELECT COMPETENZA, [CODICE CLEINTE], [RAGIONE SOCIALE], MODELLO, VARIANTE, 
  TIPOLOGIA, ESSENZA, FINITURA, TAPPEZZERIA, COMMESSA, ROUND([% MOL SU RICAVI NETTI] * 100,2) as MARGINE
  FROM OPENDATASOURCE('Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0', 
   'Data Source=K:\UTENTI\SAMUELE\temp id commesse/ID Commesse produzione.xls;Extended Properties=EXCEL 12.0')...['Consuntivi produzione$']
  WHERE MODELLO IS NOT NULL AND [% MOL SU RICAVI NETTI] IS NOT NULL
  
END
```

I really don't understand why in SQL Server it works fine and in C# not.
How can I fix this?

Comment: The problem is not your C# code, but the driver `Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0` Maybe there is something wrong in the connectionstring, or maybe something with the driver ?

Comment: @GuidoG But the "Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.16.0" is on sqlserver

Comment: _"[Microsoft **does not** currently recommend, and does not support, Automation of Microsoft Office applications from **any unattended**, non-interactive client application or component (including ASP, ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit **unstable behavior** and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment...Using server-side Automation to provide Office functionality to unlicensed workstations `is not covered by the End User License Agreement (EULA)`.](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)"_

Comment: ...and yes, [ACE OLEDB is part of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OP #1:

> I have a strange issues reading datas from an excel file. I made a query in mssql with OPENDATASOURCE:  If i execute this query in a stored procedure, it works fine.

OP #2:

> But when i execute from c# by an HttpGet i get this issues:

Firstly, that's an apples and oranges comparison.  On one hand you are using MySQL and the other SQL Server. The latter case you also have a web app using ADO.NET in order to reach the stored proc.

Now I can't vouch for MySQL or whatever `OPENDATASOURCE` is doing in both occasions but one thing is certain - you appear to be using ACE OLEDB "Jet" in a server setting which may be the cause of your issues.  Crashes aside, using ACE might have licensing issues. See below.

Microsoft (my emphasis):

> Although such programmatic development can be implemented on a client system with relative ease, a number of **complications** can occur if **Automation takes place from server-side** code such as Microsoft **Active Server Pages** (ASP), ASP.NET, DCOM, or a **Windows NT service**.

> NOTE: In this context, the **Access Database Engine Redistributable** and **Access Runtime** are considered **Microsoft Office** components.

...and:

> Developers who try to use Office in a server-side solution **need to be aware** of five major areas in which **Office** behaves **differently** than anticipated because of the environment.

...and most importantly (my emphasis):

> Besides the technical problems, you must also consider **licensing issues**. Current licensing guidelines **prevent Office applications from being used on a server to service client requests**, unless those clients themselves have licensed copies of Office. Using server-side Automation to provide Office functionality to unlicensed workstations **is not covered by the End User License Agreement (EULA)**.

### Conclusion

So even if you fix the technical issue, be mindful of that last pointer.

### See also

- [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/topic/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office-48bcfe93-8a89-47f1-0bce-017433ad79e2), Microsoft

Comment: I don't understand why, c# send to sql server to execute the stored procedure, so sql server execute the SP right? So assuming that the query works, why not working?

Comment: @SamueleBolzan did you read the link?  You're using ACE.OLEDB in a server environment and to make matters worse in a stored proc in SQL Server.  SQL Server could be running as LOCALSERVICE for all we know.  Apart from that, you might not be allowed to run it.  I suggest you read the article as I can't too it justice.

Comment: Licencing is explicitly off-topic for [so] so I don't see why you should even mention it

Comment: @Charlieface Licensing _questions_ are off-topic on Stack Overflow not an answer with a _oh by the way, have you read **this**?_  I thought I made it pretty clear in the Conclusion.